# Youtube video keeps goint to Start when seeking

Tags: flutter, youtubeplayer

I am using this [youtube player flutter package](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter). but whenever move the seek bar the video restarts. also sometimes the total video duration is also wrong... need a suggestion.. thanks in advance

```
YoutubePlayer(
    controller: _controller,
    bottomActions: [
      CurrentPosition(),
      ProgressBar(isExpanded: true),
      RemainingDuration(),
    ],
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone has the same issue here is the link of Github project in which I did some changes in the 'Progressbar.dart' file : [github link](https://github.com/Sourabhbankar/youtube_player_flutter.git)